# Protractor Test - How to Reset Mouse Location to Default Origin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, mousemove

I am using protractor for e2e testing and I am using more then one test spec.
From one test spec to another I notice that my mouse is left in the last location of where it was from the previous spec.

What I would like is for the mouse to start from a default location with each spec. 
I believe would be the upper left hand corner.

The goal is that I know where my mouse starts at the beginning of each test and I can right my test accordingly and each test will start with the mouse at the same baseline.

For Example:

```
//Assume this is the first spec
browser.actions().mouseMove(x: 15, y: 25).perform().then(function() {
    //code
});

//If this is in another spec, this mouseMove  will start from the x: 15 & y: 25 location
browser.actions().mouseMove(x: 153, y: 125).perform().then(function() {
    //code
});
```

Comment: Anyone find it's resolution? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before or after every test manually mouse move to the "0, 0":

```
browser.actions().mouseMove({x: 0, y: 0}).perform();
```